# Zooming specific point of a DWG File

Tags: c#, autocad, dwg

I am new to Autocad. I have a `dwg` drawing which include information related to a plan of an area. I am developing a small Windows Application where the user can input a desired city and the application will open the `dwg` file in a `Autocad.exe` zooming the given  city. I would like to know whether it is possible to open the `dwg` drawing zooming the area of user provided city of the plan, using C#. If so please guide with a sample code segment.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation contains [sample code](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-B44F15B0-BF4A-48ED-AA86-5445075B94BD.htm,topicNumber=d30e718877). This code must be running in the AutoCAD process. Communicating with an out-of-process executable is complicated, but possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Is there any possibility to read the X,Y coordinates of the user given city from the DWG file and then pass them to the zooming function in sample code. Is it possible to feed the coordinate information to autocad.exe when opening the drawing via the C# application?